# fsarchiver utility in order to make restore

Tags: backup, restore, selinux

I use the fsarchiver in order to make restore as the following

link: http://www.icewalkers.com/Linux/Software/535640/fsarchiver.html

command:

```
      fsarchiver restfs /tmp/backup/c0d0p2.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/cciss/c0d0p2
```

its fail on:

```
          [errno=22, Invalid argument]: oper_restore.c#213,extractar_restore_attr_xattr(): xattr:lsetxattr(/racoon,security.selinux) failed Statistics for filesystem 0
```

please help what is it: errno=22 ???

Comment: Well, errno=22 means “invalid argument”. But I don't know what this error means here. More information would help: under what distribution are you running this? What does the image contain (what filesystem, for a start)?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you could try [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). If you post there, make sure to link your questions to each other. And do include as much information as you can.

Answer (score 0):

`errno(3)` numbers can be found in GNU/Linux in this file:

```
 $ grep 22 /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h

 #define EINVAL          22      /* Invalid argument */
```

The error in this case is saying that fsarchiver is not able to restore the extended attributtes of the files.

Mandatory Access Control (MAC) attibutes, as implemented by SELinux, are stored in the `xattr` of the file(s)/directory.

From the fsarchiver [wiki](http://www.fsarchiver.org/QuickStart):

> It's also important that you make sure that SELinux is not enabled in the kernel running FSArchiver when you save a file-system which has been labeled by SELinux, or you can use FSArchiver with SELinux enabled if you are sure that the context where it's running has enough privileges to read the extended-attributes related to SELinux. In the other cases, the kernel could return unlabeled instead of the real value of the security.selinux attribute. Then FSArchiver would not preserve these attributes and then the system would not work when you restore your root filesystem, or you would have to ask the SELinux to relabel the file-system. The SELinux support is disabled by default if you use FSArchiver from SystemRescueCd-1.1.3 or newer, so your SELinux labels will be preserved if you use FSArchiver from that environment.